# JQuery RS Carousel - how to drag according to mouse position and not by page

Tags: jquery, carousel, drag

Using [jquery rs carousel](https://github.com/richardscarrott/jquery-ui-carousel), I wanted to drag the content gradually just according to mouse position and not just snapping per page. Currently, the carousel will just snap to next/prev page or slide back to position if not dragged harder... I don't want that. I would like to achieve is something like from [TouchCarousel](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/touchcarousel/#carousel-image-and-text).

I prefer rs-carousel 'cause its dynamic and most of the feature I want is there. So how do I fix/change this "dragging" thing?

Btw, I have other rs-carousels on other pages which are fine already. It would be nice if the fix will not affect them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved without any JavaScript; you just need to set the overflow on `.rs-carousel-mask`:

```
.rs-carousel-mask {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

The only difference is you won't have click and drag on non-touch devices, it'd just be native scrolling.

If you need to use it in conjunction with the carousel controls (so pages as well) you'd have to update the carousel's internal `$(':rs-carousel').data('carousel').page` index on scroll depending on scroll position which shouldn't be too difficult.